# What's the difference between these watch expressions?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

### Scope property:

- `$scope.$watch('foo', fn)`
- `$scope.$watch(function() {return $scope.foo}, fn)`

### Non-scope objects:

- `$scope.$watch(obj.prop, fn)`
- `$scope.$watch(function() {return obj.prop}, fn)`

The pair with non-scope objects produced different outcomes, as in the former expression didn't execute when obj.prop changed. But why?

Comment: which is the second one? the non scope one or the function with a return value? and what were the different outcomes?

Comment: Thanks, I would add an answer but @Fresheyeball 's answer is pretty clear and simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.$watch('foo', fn)`

This will use the `$parse` service to watch the value of `$scope.foo`, and will compare old values against new.

`$scope.$watch(function() {return $scope.foo}, fn)`

This is the same as the first, but uses a lambda. The `function() {return $scope.foo}` will be executed on each `$digest`, the old `return` values will be compared with `return` new.

`$scope.$watch(obj.prop, fn)`

This one is weird and not-recommended, because its behavior depends entirely on the type of `obj.prop`. For example if `obj.prop === "foo"`, then it will be the same as `$scope.$watch('foo', fn)`. If `obj.prop === function(){ return Math.random(); }` then you got a weird thing. If you are expecting **angular** to `$watch` the value of `obj.prop` for changes to `obj.prop`, it wont work this way.

`$scope.$watch(function() {return obj.prop}, fn)`

This one is the same as `$scope.$watch(function() {return $scope.foo}, fn)` in that **angular** will run the lambda `function() {return obj.prop}` each `$digest`. Old `return` values will be compared to the new. What you have here is ultimately to proper way to watch something that is not on `$scope`. It will monitor `obj.prop` for changes (because its the `return` value).

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the code, and this is how it goes down:

### $watch

```
$watch: function(watchExp, listener, objectEquality) {
  var get = $parse(watchExp);
  if (get.$$watchDelegate) {
    return get.$$watchDelegate(this, listener, objectEquality, get);
  }
  var scope = this,
      array = scope.$$watchers,
      watcher = {
        fn: listener,
        last: initWatchVal,
        get: get,
        exp: watchExp,
        eq: !!objectEquality
      };
  lastDirtyWatch = null;
  if (!isFunction(listener)) {
    watcher.fn = noop;
  }
  if (!array) {
    array = scope.$$watchers = [];
  }
  // we use unshift since we use a while loop in $digest for speed.
  // the while loop reads in reverse order.
  array.unshift(watcher);
  return function deregisterWatch() {
    arrayRemove(array, watcher);
    lastDirtyWatch = null;
  };
},
```

So when the comparison executes, to see if `(value = watch.get(current)) !== (last = watch.last)`, which is basically calling the `get` in the second line of `$watch` and compare its new value with the stored one. To know what `get` is, I had a look at `$parse`:

### $parse

```
return function $parse(exp, interceptorFn) {
  var parsedExpression, oneTime, cacheKey;
  switch (typeof exp) {
    case 'string':
      cacheKey = exp = exp.trim();
      parsedExpression = cache[cacheKey];
      if (!parsedExpression) {
        if (exp.charAt(0) === ':' && exp.charAt(1) === ':') {
          oneTime = true;
          exp = exp.substring(2);
        }
        var lexer = new Lexer($parseOptions);
        var parser = new Parser(lexer, $filter, $parseOptions);
        parsedExpression = parser.parse(exp);
        if (parsedExpression.constant) {
          parsedExpression.$$watchDelegate = constantWatchDelegate;
        } else if (oneTime) {
          //oneTime is not part of the exp passed to the Parser so we may have to
          //wrap the parsedExpression before adding a $$watchDelegate
          parsedExpression = wrapSharedExpression(parsedExpression);
          parsedExpression.$$watchDelegate = parsedExpression.literal ?
            oneTimeLiteralWatchDelegate : oneTimeWatchDelegate;
        } else if (parsedExpression.inputs) {
          parsedExpression.$$watchDelegate = inputsWatchDelegate;
        }
        cache[cacheKey] = parsedExpression;
      }
      return addInterceptor(parsedExpression, interceptorFn);
    case 'function':
      return addInterceptor(exp, interceptorFn);
    default:
      return addInterceptor(noop, interceptorFn);
  }
};
```

Basically, it has different cases for what the watched expression's type is. It has `string`, `function`, and `default`.

What it means is that if my watched expression `obj.prop` evaluated to:

1. type `string`, e.g., `'foo'`, it will be treated exactly like a `$scope.foo` case.
2. type `function`, which gets passed into `$parse(watchExp)` without a second parameter, it'll be returned as is with `addInterceptor`, and gets executed within each `$digest`, its returned value as the value to be compared against.
3. other types, would get dealt with by `addInterceptor(noop, interceptorFn)` without a `interceptorFn`. And since `noop` is just an empty angular function, this one wouldn't do anything.

### Conclusion

So if I'd wanted to check a `obj.prop` that's not part of the $scope, I should go with the function returning value route, the `$scope.$watch(function() {return obj.prop}, fn)`.